# How can you use BreezeJS without Entity Framework and OData?

Tags: breeze

How can Breeze JS be used to consume a pure, simple, plain old RESTful API? Consider a web api endpoint that does not support OData and does not have Microsoft Entity Framework as the OR/M layer.

I see there's this Edmund's sample [here](http://breeze.github.io/doc-samples/edmunds.html), but I would like it to be more specific on how to manually setup BreezeJS metadata, since from what I understand about not having OData support is the fact that you lose out-of-the-box metadata resolution for the model consumed from an api endpoint. I quote from this Edmund example:

> we have not yet described the Metadata Definition API properly. We ask that you rely on your intuition as you read this code ... your intuition will usually be correct. Please post questions to StackOveflow tagged with "breeze".

Is there any source of information on this topic that leaves intuition aside?

Answer (score 1):

That Edmunds sample is so old, it pre-dates any of the documentation on how to write metadata.

Take a look at the [Metadata by Hand](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/metadata-by-hand.html) topic in the BreezeJS documentation.